# My SignUp page in html using firebase isnt working

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im a beginner and im trying to make a site for my company and using firebase auth im trying to create a signup page, my problem is that when a try to register an account it doesnt register, I click the button and nothing happens, if someone can help i would be very happy :)

```
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.min.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Belgrani Stock</title>

  <!-- update the version number as needed -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.10/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
  <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.10/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.10/firebase-database-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.10/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.10/firebase-functions-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.10/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.10/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.10/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.10/firebase-remote-config-compat.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.6.10/firebase-performance-compat.js"></script>
  <!-- 
      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h3>Registar</h3>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Palavra-Passe" id="password">
    <br>
    <button id="signUp">Registar</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyAcZ4alDvYt1Z4aAYwwG6nTPJPs6fTQzl4",
      authDomain: "belgrani-stock.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "belgrani-stock",
      storageBucket: "belgrani-stock.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "478225091410",
      appId: "1:478225091410:web:7de036685c07dd7c88488b",
      measurementId: "G-H94BFSJNET"
    };


    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

    document.getElementById('signUp').addEventListener('click', signUpUser)

    function signUpUser(){
      let email = document.getElementById('email').value
      let password = document.getElementById('password').value

      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).catch(e=>{
        console.log(e)
      })
 
    }
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
      if(user){
        console.log(user)
      }else{
        
      }
    })
```

I know its probably a easy fix but im a very new beginner and im lost in this.

Comment: Heres a link that can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638202/firebase-web-login-not-working I hope i helped :)

Comment: From what I have seen most places is, use firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).
Try this out.